# Problemas con proyectos c++ en visual studio 2013

Tags: c++

Intento crear un proyecto aplicacion de consola win32 en lenguaje c++ y me crea la solucion y el proyecto pero sin las carpetas que se crean por defecto y ademas me cierra el visual studio y ni siquiera puedo crear un archivo cpp [image: Al crear el proyecto]

[image: Me dice que cree de nuevo el proyecto pero si le doy cancelar me cierra el visual (dejo de funcionar y se está reiniciando, en un mensaje) y de ahi no pasa, no puedo crear archivos cpp ni carpetas]

Al crear el proyecto (imagen 1)

Me dice que cree de nuevo el proyecto pero si le doy cancelar me cierra el visual (dejo de funcionar y se está reiniciando, en un mensaje) y de ahi no pasa, no puedo crear archivos cpp ni carpetas (Imagen 2)

Comment: trata de elegir crear una aplicacion C++ pero no le pongas Win32, proba ponerle General a ver si sigue pasando el mismo problema.

Comment: @riks si tienes la licencia original, contacta con el soporte, tengo la misma versión que tú desde que salió y nunca he tenido ese problema...

Comment: no pude solucionarlo, tendria que contactar con soporte pero igual estoy usando la version community para estudiar por ahora, instalé el visual 2010 jaja ese si me funciono perfecto, gracias igualmente.